# Solidity stuck at mining transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity

i am trying to deploy a contract in the ethereum blockchain with solidity. When i press the create button directly under it, a message saying "Waiting for transaction to be mined..." shows up indefinitely. The contract i am trying to deploy is pretty simple and straight forward and i got it from a youtube tutorial. In the tutorial, after pressing the create button the metamask plugin pops up a message to make sure you want to deploy the contract which in my case it doesn't since it is stuck at "Waiting for transaction to be mined... ". any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum testnet was reset and the new testnet is called Ropsten. Since the change, the solidity web compiler had some issues and will hopefully be resolved soon. Meanwhile try to use clients such as geth or parity or just download mist. 
(thanks to shlomi zeltsinger)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using an private network for testing purposes. There's a link on how to do it here: 
https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

Try checking if the javascript console desn't show any error. It is common that some versions of browser-solidity that have some issues with bignumbers. (I've picket up a good branch here: https://github.com/oraclize/browser-solidity/network)

Try increasing your gas limit. It is possible that you don't have enough gas to store the contract.

Lastly, if everything fails, try adding it using the geth console, inputing the bytecode generated directly there

Comment: Thank you for your input, the problem was that since the change to Ropsten testnet solidity had some problems. Now i can deploy contracts without any errors.